# How to record(storing) the values in a file during silent Installation?

Tags: nsis, silent-installer

I am generating exe using NSIS installer

In GUI,we will have

```
Default Installation Location
IP Address and Port
```

And we will store these IP Address and Port in a file named config.ini and later we will use that file

But now,we are installing it silently(Silent Installation).So we can't capture IPAddress and Port.It is being empty in a config.ini file.

Million thanks to the one who will get me rid of this.

Because I have read NSIS forums and other websites,But I can't get any solutions

Help me with this :)

So we

Answer (score 0):

Let the user specify them on the command line and default to a value if no parameter is provided.:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Var Port

Function .onInit
${GetParameters} $R1
${GetOptions} $R1 "/PORT=" $Port
${If} ${Errors}
    StrCpy $Port 1234 # Default fallback
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
DetailPrint $Port
WriteINIStr $InstDir\config.ini Server Port $Port
SectionEnd
```

Run as `mysetup.exe /PORT=1337`

Comment: But we want to store these values in a config.ini file

Comment: Then just write it to the ini file. I'm sure you already know how but I edited the answer anyway.

Comment: Yeah I know but while silent installation,it is not opened my config file.Thats why I asked you.I made some changes and it worked.Thanks for your response Mr.Anders